# List All attrbutes Measures Used in PowerBi tabular

Tags: powerbi, ssas-tabular

I have a PowerBi model built on top of Tabular Solution. I want to know list of attributes/Measures used in building that tabular..

Comment: PowerBi dashboard to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Log into PowerPivot via a spreadsheet.  Connect your spreadsheet to the Tabular Cube/Solution.  Once connected you will see all the measures and attributes on the left hand side of the PowerPivot window.